# Increasing font size in PHP code and align text in center of captcha image

Tags: php, html, css

I have a following PHP code which generates and gives me captcha. The captcha code lies on the top left corner of 180x60 background image (fuzzy type captcha background image). And its about 12px in size. I want to bring it to the exect center of the image with font size of 18px or more (adjustable). But, I am not sure how to do it as its very confusing to edit a code like this.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $ranStr = md5(microtime());
    $ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
    $_SESSION['cap_code'] = $ranStr;
    $newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/cap_bg.jpg");
    $txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($newImage);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i know its not the question but using [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html) is a much better idea than writing your own

Comment: You are right but its already integrated now. I  just to adjust the font here which I am confused how to do.

Comment: [imagestring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) defines font size and position

Comment: Can you post an example of the current output you're getting?

Comment: what to change there? 5,5,5 ?? Should I play with them and try to alter them?

Comment: I altered it to 10,65,22.. 65,22 brought it to center... changing 1st digit from 5 to 10 increased font size a bit.. trying to increase more but its not working here..

Comment: sorry I was wrong.. font-size is not increasing.. its the same as it was in 5.. also decreasing the font size is working fine but its not increasing the font size...

Comment: @ishegg here is the screenshot after changing the values to 5,65,22. https://prnt.sc/gaycdk

Comment: my mistake, if you want to control font size you will need to use  [imagettftext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Comment: @rtfm can you post it as an answer how to do it so that I can accept it and it will help others facing the same issue looking for a solution? Please show with my code how to do it.. thanks